# Question o Trigonometrical equation

Tags: trigonometry

I'm know confused by an equation involving $tan$

Given: $tan\bigl(x - \dfrac{\pi}{4}) \le 1$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$.

Adjusting the bound for $x - \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ it becomes $\dfrac{-5\pi}{4} < x < \dfrac{3\pi}{4}$.

Finding $x = 1$ boundaries, $x = \dfrac{-3\pi}{4}, \dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Resulting in intervals with $tan\bigl(x - \dfrac{\pi}{4}) <= 1$ are:

$-\pi < x < -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, -\dfrac{\pi}{4} < x < \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{3\pi}{4} < x < \pi$

But wolfram gives different results for where all my $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ bound should be $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Can someone show me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning, you may be wrong.

Let $x-\frac{\pi}{4}=X$, then we have 
$$-\frac{5}{4}\pi\lt X\lt \frac{3}{4}\pi.$$

Don't confuse with $x$. You then need to solve for $X$ such that 
$$-\frac{5}{4}\pi\lt X\lt \frac{3}{4}\pi\ \ \text{and}\ \ \tan X\le 1.$$